# TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am new to coding, I am trying to build an app that adds items to an order. I want the quantity to increase when an item is selected twice rather than list the item twice.

Using index of, I get this error:

> TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Trying other things I get an error saying `indexOf` is not a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not completely knew to web technologies, I know HTML, CSS and bits of PHP but I'm new to javascript/typescript. Thanks again for your help though.

Comment: Then don't say "I'm new to coding", my comment would have been quite different.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the object of the array before accessing the property of the object.

`this.orderProvider.orders.itemName[i].indexOf(itemName)`

should be

`this.orderProvider.orders[i].itemName.indexOf(itemName)`

since you are looping through all the objects of `this.orderProvider.orders` having your loop condition as `this.orderProvider.orders.length` which means that you need to access each object inside `this.orderProvider.orders` before you can access the property `itemName`.

Comment: thank you so much! thank you for also explaining, that really helps and makes total sense!

Comment: @idkwhatimdoing glad to help you